# getting article title from joomla into a plugin

Tags: php, joomla

So I have this working PHP code to get the Joomla currently displayed article:

```
<?php
    $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
    $view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    echo $article->get("title");
}
else {
    echo "Error - not an article";
}
?>
```

Which I've successfully used in ChronoForms to get my article name for emailing to clients, which happens to be a tendering website with an ID code at the end of each article name, such as 12345.

Is there any quick and dirty way to insert this code somewhere in joomla so I can dynamically modify my plugin's in article, such as:

```
{gallery}12345{/gallery}
```

I tried adding it directly into a template, but came out with various problems no matter where I inserted it (top, bottom, middle)
I also tried a PHP in article joomla add-on, but that code stopped the page displaying.

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamically modify my plugin's in article"?
You should be able to run this from a content plugin with a regexpr you would catch the code and replace it.

Comment: Okay, so the title of the article, is for example "12345", and i have a plugin {gallery}12345{/gallery} in that article, how can i insert the title in between the {gallery}here!{/gallery}.

Comment: At this stage I'm thinking of some kind of templating system or adding the get_title code directly into the gallery plug-in, but don't really want to wade through someone else's code

Answer (score 0):

based on comments this is what I understand; please correct me if I got this wrong.

You have some articles which contain the code

```
{gallery}here!{/gallery}
```

which a plugin should replace with

```
 {gallery}The title of the article{/gallery}
```

If so, this will need to happen on com_content, view=article where Joomla will make available to the plugin's onContentBeforeDisplay() the article object.

```
function onContentBeforeDisplay($context, &$article, &$params, $page=0){
    $view     = JRequest::getCmd('view'); 
    if ($view == 'article') {
        $content = $article->text;  
        $title = $article->title;
        $content = preg_replace('/{gallery}.*{\/gallery}/',"{gallery}$title{/gallery}",$content);
        $article->text = $content;
    }
}
```

If however you need the title of another article, or you need it outside of com_content view=article, then you would have to instantiate com_content and grab it from there.